# Microsoft Azure Storage denying my OneClick application from downloading

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, oneclick, one-click-web-publishing

Through MAS, I have a blob container setup with public access level set to "Public read access for blobs only", allowing for a download of the `setup.exe` by visiting "https://myblob.blob.core.windows.net/myprogram/myprogram.htm". The problem stems from actually running `setup.exe` in that it gives me

```
The following properties have been set:
Property: [AdminUser] = true {boolean}
Property: [InstallMode] = HomeSite {string}
Property: [NTProductType] = 1 {int}
Property: [ProcessorArchitecture] = AMD64 {string}
Property: [VersionNT] = 10.0.0 {version}
Running checks for package 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2 (x86 and x64)', phase BuildList
Reading value 'Release' of registry key 'HKLM\Software\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full'
Read integer value 460805
Setting value '460805 {int}' for property 'DotNet45Full_Release'
Reading value 'v4' of registry key 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\OS Integration'
Read integer value 1
Setting value '1 {int}' for property 'DotNet45Full_OSIntegrated'
The following properties have been set for package 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2 (x86 and x64)':
Property: [DotNet45Full_OSIntegrated] = 1 {int}
Property: [DotNet45Full_Release] = 460805 {int}
Running checks for command 'DotNetFX452\NDP452-KB2901907-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe'
Result of running operator 'ValueEqualTo' on property 'InstallMode' and value 'HomeSite': true
Result of checks for command 'DotNetFX452\NDP452-KB2901907-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe' is 'Bypass'
Running checks for command 'DotNetFX452\NDP452-KB2901907-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe'
Result of running operator 'ValueEqualTo' on property 'InstallMode' and value 'HomeSite': true
Result of checks for command 'DotNetFX452\NDP452-KB2901907-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe' is 'Bypass'
Running checks for command 'DotNetFX452\NDP452-KB2901954-Web.exe'
Result of running operator 'ValueNotEqualTo' on property 'InstallMode' and value 'HomeSite': false
Result of running operator 'ValueGreaterThanEqualTo' on property 'DotNet45Full_Release' and value '379893': true
Result of checks for command 'DotNetFX452\NDP452-KB2901954-Web.exe' is 'Bypass'
Running checks for command 'DotNetFX452\NDP452-KB2901954-Web.exe'
Result of running operator 'ValueNotEqualTo' on property 'InstallMode' and value 'HomeSite': false
Result of running operator 'ValueGreaterThanEqualTo' on property 'DotNet45Full_Release' and value '379893': true
Result of checks for command 'DotNetFX452\NDP452-KB2901954-Web.exe' is 'Bypass'
'Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2 (x86 and x64)' RunCheck result: No Install Needed
Launching Application.
URLDownloadToCacheFile failed with HRESULT '-2146697210'
Error: An error occurred trying to download 'https://myblob.blob.core.windows.net/myprogram/publish.htm/myprogram.application'.
```

I get the feeling I'm missing a setting for MAS somewhere but I'm not sure where to look

Comment: Can you please check if the blob container's ACL is not `Private`? Otherwise, please share the actual URL of your application.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had set the deployment URL in VisualStudio to `https://myblob.blob.core.windows.net/myprogram/myprogram.htm` rather than just `https://myblob.blob.core.windows.net/myprogram` which meant it was trying to look for files under `https://myblob.blob.core.windows.net/myprogram/myprogram.htm/<Setup files>`